# Managing Line Feed Between Delphi And HTML

Tags: php, html, delphi

I have a delphi application that sends data through the TMS TWEBPOST component to a php script.
This script then converts the data sent into a `$_GET` compatible url and posts it to get a return page.

The code works perfectly, except when I try to post multiline content, in the `$_POST` array I see it simply shows the text in 1 long line, but after converting it to a `$_GET` compatible url I see the following in the place of a blank line `%0D%0A%0D%0A` so, what should look like:

```
You must leave all houses alone...

Now go in peace
```

Looks Like `You must leave all houses alone...  Now go in peace`

is there anyway to resolve this issue and make the html website read the `%0D%0A` as a blank line?

Comment: how about a simple string replacement?

Comment: Hi @Dagon that was my first thought. But it is asif I cannot get access to the string, I will post an update now with the result i had before.

Comment: "cannot get access to the string" not sure what that means here

Comment: @dagon it was my mistake, I was trying to get access to the `%0D%0A` in the `$_POST` variable, which does not work, But after it is converted to the URL i am able to access it. I am just not sure what caracter works as a line feed in html I tried `&#10;` as suggested here https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_13.html but it does not work, just makes small blocks in the place of the `&#10;`

Comment: @dagon Sorry was over complicating it, simply adding `urlencode("<br>")`  in the place of the `%0D%0A` solved the issue. Thanks for the help :)